# How can I create an image from a STEP file in python

Tags: python, 3d, cad, step, freecad

I currently have a python script using the freecad API to read a step file and send some data to an excel file (volume, dimensions, etc.) with xlwings. I would like to also add a view of the STEP file. Is there a way using python to get an image from step file?

I've seen in the freeCAD docs that you can use something like this:

> FreeCADGui.ActiveDocument.ActiveView.saveImage(filePath)

But I am not running the GUI, so this option currently does not work for me.